# Can getmail send messages over SMTP?

Tags: getmail

I started using getmail yesterday. Before I used `offlineimap` to receive messages and `sendmail` to send them. The [documentation](http://pyropus.ca/software/getmail/documentation.html) says:

> reliability: ... does not cause mail loops by doing SMTP injection, and therefore does not require that you run an MTA (like qmail or sendmail) on your host

When I compose an email, the mini-buffer window asks if I want to use the default, and opens Apple Mail with the draft when I click OK.

I could not find a configuration for `getmail` with SMTP, so I wanted to confirm: do I still need to use an agent like `sendmail` to send emails over SMTP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`getmail`](http://pyropus.ca/software/getmail/) only gets mail.  It does not send mail.

It fetches mail from a variety of different type of mail services and writes the messages directly to a local mail folder or delivers them through an MDA.  The text that you quote means that `getmail` will not inject its messages into the local mail server for delivery.

You do not need to run `sendmail` or `qmail` to use `getmail`.

You *do* need to run `sendmail` or `qmail`, or similar MTA-capable software, *to send mail*.